# MongoDB return specific fields from array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to limit my query's result to a set of fields. This is one of my documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "WA9QRuiWtGsr4amtT",
    "status" : 3,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "0",
            "value" : "Text ..."
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "1",
            "value" : "12345678"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "2",
            "value" : "Text"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "4",
            "value" : "2"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "8",
            "value" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "26",
            "value" : true
        },
    ],
    "userId" : "7ouEumtudgC2HX4fF",
    "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1415903962863)
}
```

I want to limit the output to the status field as well a the first and third data document.

This is what I tried:

```
Meteor.publish('cases', function () {

  var fields = {
    currentStatus: 1,
    'data.0': 1,
    'data.2': 1
  };

  return Cases.find({}, { fields: fields });
});
```

Sadly it doesn't work. Something else I found is $elemMatch but it only returns the first element:

```
data: { 
  $elemMatch: { 
    name: { 
      $in: ['0', '2']
    }
  }
},
```

How can I limit the output to these fields?

Comment: How about data.[0] or data[0]? Without ''

Answer (score 0):

To display status and data(unlimited) fields try

```
cases.find({}, {"status":1, "data":1})
```

This is simple query, to limit "data" output you will need to work harder :)

Get 1 element by data.name (not by position):

```
cases.find({}, {status:1, "data": {$elemMatch:{name:"0"}}})
```

Get 1 element by data.name, but from a list of values:

```
cases.find({}, {status:1, "data": {$elemMatch:{name:{$in:["0", "1"]}}}})
```

To get close to your question, you may try [redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/). That is new in Mongodb 2.6.
Or play with $unwind and .aggregate() in previous editions.

So far, I do not see a way to return array elements based on a position.